# IIS7: Setting far future expires header on specific files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

In IIS7 I am trying to set a really far future expires header for all content that have the file name that has a specific word in it.   For example I would like to set this header on any file being requested from IIS7 that is

```
*cached*.js
```

I know that it is possible to set far future expires headers, But I want to know if it is possible to set it on *specific files* like in the example above.

I want to use this method on a .NET application I am trying to serve up, but I want to make it more efficient so that certain files will be cached for a very long time, because it virtually never changes.  **At the same time I don't want to be restricted to doing it for all files in a certain folder or all files of certain type.**

I am open to doing this through modifying my Asp.Net application to achieve this, or through IIS7 settings.

So guys, what do you think, is There a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HttpModule will let you do this.  That would let you look at the incoming URL then add the correct response headers.

**Edit: Added Example**

You can use [this URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) to create a basic HttpModule.  Then in the Application_BeginRequest event, I think this code will be close to what you want:

```
if (context.Request.FilePath.ToLower().IndexOf("cached") != -1)
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
```

Comment: Do you know any place I can find examples of writing a HttpModule I could use to get started?

Comment: So, there's no declarative way to do it, like there is in Apache?